# How to perfect forward a value returned from a function while returning a second value?

Tags: c++, templates, return, c++17, perfect-forwarding

I want to make a `benchmark` function that, given an invocable and its parameters, will time the execution of the given invocable and return the measured `std::chrono::duration<...>` as well as the value returned by the invocation of the invocable.

I am having problems with perfect forwarding the value returned from the invocation. Currently I return the value returned by the invocation and use a reference parameter to return the duration:

```
using bench_clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, 
                      std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock>;

decltype(auto) benchmark(
   bench_clock::duration& duration, auto&& func, auto&&... args)
{
   auto begin{ bench_clock::now() };
   decltype(auto) result{ 
      std::invoke(
         std::forward<decltype(func)>(func), 
         std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...) 
   };
   duration = bench_clock::now() - begin;
   return result;
}
```

As far as I know, this perfectly forwards the value returned from the invocation.

I would prefer to also return the duration conventionally, as an example, by using `std::tuple` though I am not sure how to do it t perfectly forward the returned value.

My guess would be to use `std::invoke_result_t` like this:

```
using bench_clock = std::conditional_t<
   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, 
   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock>;

auto benchmark(auto&& func, auto&&... args)
{
   auto begin{ bench_clock::now() };
   decltype(auto) result{
      std::invoke(
         std::forward<decltype(func)>(func),
         std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...) 
   };
   auto duration{ bench_clock::now() - begin };
   return std::tuple<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(func), decltype(args)...>, bench_clock::duration>{std::forward<decltype(result)>(result), duration};
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is this needed?
}
```

I am not sure if this approach correctly perfectly forwards. I also don't know if is required to use `std::forward` in the `std::tuple` constructor.

There is also a problem, that if the invocable returns `void`, the tuple cannot be used, as `std::tuple<void>` cannot be instantiated.

I am not sure how to go around this.

Comment: not `std::forward()` for `result` but `std::move()`

Comment: For the `void` problem... you can use C++17 or only C++11/C++14?

Comment: `result` is an lvalue, it can't be perfect-forwarded. At best it can be moved into the tuple, but it won't be constructed in-place. If it's a heavy object, it's better to construct the tuple with the result, and then assign the duration part and hope for NRVO to take place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need to handle the `void` return case when you invoke the function `func` inside the `benchmark` function.

Since you have used `std::invoke_result_t` and `std::conditional_t`, I assume that you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). Then this can be easily solved by an [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) checking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_same_v,  std::invoke_result_t
#include <functional>   // std::invoke
#include <utility>      // std::forward, std::move

using namespace std::chrono;
using bench_clock = std::conditional_t<
   high_resolution_clock::is_steady, high_resolution_clock, steady_clock>;


template<typename Func, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) benchmark(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
   auto begin{ bench_clock::now() };
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, std::invoke_result_t<Func, Args...>>)
   {
       // can not have void result: therefore just invoke the func!
      std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
      return bench_clock::now() - begin; // only the time duration will be returned!
   }
   else
   {
      // all other cases return the tuple of result-duration!
      decltype(auto) result{ std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
      const auto duration{ bench_clock::now() - begin };
      return std::make_tuple(std::move(result), duration);
   }
}
```

**([See a Demo Online Live](https://godbolt.org/z/PocrGW))**